# display the output of two select statements as one in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i have this two select statements and i wanted to display them in a table i have this in my control

`$modName = DB::table('dbo_modules')
->join('dbo_modulecategory' , 'dbo_modules.CategoryID' , '=' , 'dbo_modulecategory.CategoryID')
->select('dbo_modules.ModuleID', 'dbo_modules.ModuleName', 'dbo_modulecategory.CategoryName')
->get();`

then another

```
$getModID = DB::table('dbo_purchaseorders')
->select('dbo_purchaseorders.ModuleID' , 'dbo_purchaseorders.Quantity')
->get();
```

any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the select results of two or more queries using the `union` method, see here: [union](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#unions)

So in your case, given that you have reference to either `$modName` and `$getModID`, then you can do the following:

```
$modName = DB::table('dbo_modules')
->join('dbo_modulecategory' , 'dbo_modules.CategoryID' , '=' , 'dbo_modulecategory.CategoryID')
->select('dbo_modules.ModuleID', 'dbo_modules.ModuleName', 'dbo_modulecategory.CategoryName');
```

And union here:

```
$mergedQuery = DB::table('dbo_purchaseorders')
->select('dbo_purchaseorders.ModuleID' , 'dbo_purchaseorders.Quantity')
->union($modName)
->get();
```